# How can I select select a key when shifted

Tags: javascript, dom

When I try to click on the keyboard keys like this: "/", (that requieres shift) it doesn't execute the code it is supposed to...I can't select it. Should I find another way? the complete code of my exercise is here: https://repl.it/@Sesadada/CALCULATOR

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  const key = document.querySelector(`button[data-key='${e.which}']`);
  console.log(e.which, e.shiftKey);
  if (e.which == 13) {
    equal.click();
  } else if (e.which == 8) {
    zero();
  } else {
    key.click();
  }
 
});
```

```html
<div class="nums">

  <button type="button" class="operator" data-key="80" value="%">%</button>
  <button type="button" class="operator" data-key="68" value="/">/</button>
  <button type="button" class="operator" data-key="187" value="+">+</button>
  <button type="button" class="operator" data-key="88" value="*">x</button>
  <button type="button" class="operator" data-key="189" value="-">-</button>
  <button id="zero" type="button" class="operand" data-key="48" value="0">0</button>
  <button type="button" class="equal" data-key="48" value="=">=</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.key` to get the actual character that is being passed. So when the user holds `shift + 5`, `e.key` equals `%`.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");
buttons.forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener("click", function(el) {
    console.log(el.target.value + " clicked");
  });
});
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  const key = document.querySelector(`button[value='${e.key}']`);

  if (key) {
    key.click();
  } else if (e.which == 13) {
    equal.click();
  } else if (e.which == 8) {
    zero();
  }
  //const divide = document.querySelector(
  //`button[data-key='${e.which.shiftKey}']`

  //equal.click();
});
```

```html
<div class="nums">

  <button type="button" class="operator" data-key="5" value="%">%</button>
  <button type="button" class="operator" data-key="68" value="/">/</button>
  <button type="button" class="operator" data-key="187" value="+">+</button>
  <button type="button" class="operator" data-key="88" value="*">x</button>
  <button type="button" class="operator" data-key="189" value="-">-</button>
  <button id="zero" type="button" class="operand" data-key="48" value="0">0</button>
  <button type="button" class="equal" data-key="48" value="=">=</button>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Finally! It works! I have been reading the documentation but couldn't find a way to make it work, thanks again :)